# Looping through row data

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to php. I wanted to display all user data in one page. I am doing it, but I am also getting 'undefined offset[a lot of numbers]' on that page. I know I could do "$row['data-name'] but this is if there was columns thousands of columns. Thx!

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Sorry, we couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("testsite");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$rowlen=sizeof($row);
for($i=1;$i<$rowlen;$i++){
     echo $row[$i]."<br />";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

EDIT:
Finally, figured out how to remove the first element of an associative array without knowing the name of the key! My code.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Sorry, we couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("testsite");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $row_unset=array_keys($row);
    unset($row[$row_unset[0]]);
foreach($row as $key=>$value){
    echo $value."<br />";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

or alternatively(instead of using `array_keys` function you could use a `foreach` to get the key values and push them into $row_unset

Comment: Array keys start at 0 not 1. In any case you can drop the sizeof and just use `foreach($row as $value){echo $value.'<br />';}`

Comment: Looks like an off by one error, starting `$i = 1` instead of `$i = 0`.  But I would point out that in PHP, an incremental `for` loop like this is not that often used. Instead, use a `foreach()` as in `foreach ($row as $column => $value) {... }`

Comment: And by default `mysql_fetch_array()` returns _both_ numeric and associative keys, so this will give you two of every column. Instead, I recommend `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get only the associative keys.

Comment: Also, before you get too far into mysql/php, switch the PHP interface from mysql_ to mysqli_ or PDO as mysql is going to be deprecated. Doesn't help with your question, but important for your future :-).

Comment: Sidenote to above: The use of `mysqli_` and/or PDO are not safeguards against SQL injection; not on their own that is. Using [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will.

Comment: @brechmos `s/is going to be/has already been/`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski:  s/(.*)/Thanks/g.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Thx,! I offset it by one because I wanted to ignore  the first column , the foreach works nicely for associative arrays, but now each column is printed out twice.

Comment: @user3628953 Michael already told you about that. Read the comments.

Comment: @user3628953 Thx, page refresh =P

Comment: @user3628953 Yep, as expected.  Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead, or `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` (but actually as you've been informed, you should not proceed to learn the `mysql_*()` functions. They are deprecated in favor of MySQLi or PDO)

Comment: Thx, all you guys have been helpful! One last question how can I ignore the first column while using foreach?

Answer (score 3):

Array keys start at 0 not 1 so it would be `for(var $i=0; $i<$rowlen; $i++){`

But in any case you can use [foreach](https://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
    foreach($row as $value){
        echo $value.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Also the deprecated function [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) by default returns numeric and named columns so you'll get each result twice if you don't define which you want to use.